# Activate Facebook like and facebook comment on same page

Tags: authentication, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments, facebook-login

Here is my situation.

I have two facebook likes on a single page and a single facebook comment. (using javascript sdk facebook)

I tried to like one of the facebook likes and it opens the facebook login authorization window where i enter my login details. The like works fine for that particular button only. When i click on another like button in the same page, it opens a popup window and closes it suddenly.. But no likes registered for the second button. For the another like button to work, i need to refresh the page... and the same case is with the facebook comments plugin...

Please suggest me a way such that if the user initiates the login using one of the buttons, the other facebook like and the comment will automatically work without the need to refresh the page...I got the clue to refresh the facebook plugins entirely by using
    FB.XFBML.parse();
But i don't know to attach the above function to the particular event...

Check this url

http://hillarsaare.com/projects/facebook/multi-like/

Where you can see multiple like buttons on the same page...If you are already logged in through facebook and visit that page, you will be able to like all the posts there...But if you are not logged in and visit that page, clicking one of the like buttons will prompt you to login through facebook and after logging in, you will not be able to like any other posts in the page except that post you clicked like...When you do page refresh, it will work fine...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this work-around for every like button on your page:

> Subscribing to the auth.statusChange
>   (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)
>   and check to see if it is a sucessful login. If so, re-render the like
>   button code into your DOM and then have the Javascript SDK re-parse it
>   using FB.XFBL.parse()
>   (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

Similar to:
[Facebook like button status update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079956/facebook-like-button-status-update)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.